# I have 4 integers. How I find the maximal/minimal one?

Tags: .net, algorithm

I have **4** integers(a, b, c, d).

How I find the maximal/minimal one?

What is the most **effective and efficient** method. Should I fill-in a list and then apply sort method?

.NET

Comment: Do you always have exactly 4 numbers?

Comment: That should suffice yes. Or you could do something nasty like max(a, max(b, max(c, d)));

Comment: Are you only ever going to have four? Or will you have a dynamic number and need to find the min/max?

Comment: I think you got downvoted because you used subjective terms like "effective" and "efficient" without defining them. Are you looking for the method that's easiest to type in, uses the least memory, uses the least CPU time, or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var min = Math.Min(Math.Min(a, b), Math.Min(c, d));
```

For the maximum, do the same with `Math.Max()`.

Comment: that's nicer than the triple nested version - there's scope for the two inner comparisons to happen simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

A functional approach =

```
var max = new [] { a, b, c, d }.Max();
var min = new [] { a, b, c, d }.Min();
```

Comment: I'd love it if down voters would put a reason for their downvote. Maybe I'd learn something.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but I bet your method is slower than my method (revision one which is modified and again my claim wasn't on normal cpu performance), Also I think it's slower than my normal answer, But Also you didn't describe how your method is efficeint.

Comment: Of course it is slower, but it is more efficient for the programmer, which often counts for more. It is concise and easy to read and understand, lending to clear, maintainable software. I offered it as the approach one would likely take in a functional style, since the OP left little in the way of guidance on what was meant by "efficient and effecitve".

Comment: You should describe this in your answer, I know that because of this I'm not going to downvote you, but may be is not obvious for someone and he will downvote you, may be there was another reason but this is by my point of view.

Comment: +1 for general and readable solution, even if less efficient than  @Saeed Amiri method

Answer (score 3):

If you always have exactly 4 numbers and they're already in variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, sorting is pointless because it requires putting them in an array and then sorting the array. The most efficient thing to do is just put in a few `if` statements:

```
int min1, max1;
if (a > b)
{
    min1 = b;
    max1 = a;
}
else
{
    min1 = a;
    max1 = b;
}
int min2, max2;
if (c > d)
{
    min2 = d;
    max2 = c;
}
else
{
    min2 = c;
    max2 = d;
}
int min = min1, max = max1;
if (min2 < min1)
    min = min2;
if (max2 > max1)
    max = max2;
```

Comment: How this is few if statements?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Computing the min or max of 4 numbers requires at least 3 comparisons. This is the fewest possible. Of course you could write `if` as `?:` or call functions, but neither of them would do anything different.

Comment: computing both Min and Max needs 4 comparison, you can see my answer, currently you used 6 comparison, in fact you can skip some comparisons, it's not related to use `?:` this is `if then else` and has just one comparison (or one assembly jump).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Yes, you're right. I forgot that computing both min and max simultaneously can make things slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If by efficiency you mean minimum comparision to find both max and min I think you can do as below:

```
int[] maxMin1 = (a>b)?new []{a,b}:new []{b,a};
int[] maxMin2 = (c>d)?new []{c,d}:new []{d,c};

max = Math.Max(maxMin1[0],maxMin2[0]);
min = Math.Min(maxMin1[1],maxMin2[1]);
```

It uses 4 comparison to find both of them, normal work uses 6 comparison, Also instead of array you can define a struct or class to make it more readable.

**Edit:** for testing this it's better to use some custom type, In this case I'll using `Point` which is available in .net (but it's better to have a class of custom type):

```
// one time creation:

var min = new Point {X=0,Y=0};
var max = new Point {X=0,Y=0};
.....
..... 
if (a<b)
{
    min.X = a;
    max.X = b;
}
else 
    {
        min.X = b;
        max.X = a;
    }

if (c<d)
{
   min.Y = c;
   max.Y = d;
}
else
{
   min.Y = d;
   max.Y = c;
}

var finalMin = Math.Min(min.X, min.Y);
var finalmax = Math.Max(max.X, max.Y);
```

Comment: How is this better than the other answers? Not only is it unclear, but it creates objects to do comparison as well! If you're going to chose one evil, dispense with the other...

Comment: @codekaizen you can read why it can be better, and I describe it in my answer, I said that if by efficiency comparison is important for the op, if the number of this 4 items is big and should calculate both min and max, with one time object creation, you can use this way, Also I said it can change to use some user define class to be more readable, and I don't think it's hard for anyone to do this.

Comment: I doubt that creating an array is better for speed, even though there are fewer operations. Recall that the CLR has reference arrays, not stack allocated arrays like are straightforward in C++. Creating arrays like this puts pressure on the GC, and performance will degrade. Also, going through all the effort to create a custom type for this simple problem, especially when there are exising operators to do this for us with LINQ does not appeal to my sense of "being better" for the programmer.

Comment: Some testing seems to bear out my reasoning: `Arrays: 1507ms;
No arrays: 1079ms`

http://pastebin.com/L9nPBDhW

Comment: @codekaizen First of all I edited my answer to describe it well, second your bench mark is not good, in it's current state you change the position of my way and other way you will get anther result, second, generating random number should be out of calculating min and max, in fact you can have an array of n random number and compare each 4 consecutive number, and at last If you use my above way you will get better result. Also for example in parallel computing decisions are important not assignments, so because of this I said if by "efficiency you mean number of comparison.." first line ...

Comment: In fact I don't have any claim on my algorithm which is run faster in O(1) number of processors.

Comment: Yes, I should have also changed the order of the trials, but it doesn't change much; my observation still holds: `No arrays: 1174ms; Arrays: 1487ms`. The random calculations are the same bias in each test, so don't skew the results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5366/discussion-between-saeed-amiri-and-codekaizen)

Comment: @codekaizen, after this conversation ! I think you should remove your downvote.

Answer (score 3):

One more solution that minimizes the number of comparisons

```
var max1 = Math.Max(a,b);
var max2 = Math.Max(c,d);

var max = Math.Max(max1, max2);
var min = Math.Min(a+b-max1, c+d-max2);
```

Just 4 comparisons

Comment: 4 comparisons, but finally, more operations?! :)

Comment: It is not the most efficient solution in terms of operations, but it is elegant and "efficient" in terms on numbers of comparions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method:

```
    public int FindMaxInt(params int[] numbers)
    {
        return numbers.Max();
    }
```

And then use it as follows:

`FindMaxInt(1,2,3,4,5,6);`

Or, of course, you could cut out the middleman:

`var max = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.Max();`

Or, if you want to just use one array and find the min/max from that:

```
int[] numbers = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int max = numbers.Max();
int min = numbers.Min();
```

Comment: This is hardly the most efficient, as it will require creating separate arrays to compute the min and the max, but it is certainly the cleanest.

Comment: @Gabe - it is the most effective and efficient for the programmer, which often counts for more!

Comment: @Gabe Fair enough, updated to include a single array example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are 32-bit signed ints and they are all in the range from -2<sup>30</sup> to 2<sup>30</sup>-1 and that when ints are shifted right, they're shifted arithmetically and preserve the sign bit... Assuming all of that, you can avoid all comparisons and conditional jumps and to some extent calculate things in parallel. Here's how to find the minimum:

```
using System;
public class Exercise
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 100;
    int c = -33;
    int d = -1000;
    int tmp1 = (a - b) >> 31;
    int tmp2 = (c - d) >> 31;
    int min1 = (tmp1 & a) | (~tmp1 & b);
    int min2 = (tmp2 & c) | (~tmp2 & d);
    tmp1 = (min1 - min2) >> 31;
    int min = (tmp1 & min1) | (~tmp1 & min2);
    Console.WriteLine(min);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
-1000
```

You can add 4 more lines of code to get the maximum as well.

[Code on ideone](http://ideone.com/nggOX)